# Colocações dativo-pronominais — possíveis ou impossíveis?

Tags: colocação-pronominal

A propósito do assunto, nas frases abaixo qual ou quais das construções "dativo-enclíticas" ou "enclítico-dativas", se antes disso as considerarmos corretas, se aplicariam às frases com objeto?

- Max, preciso da chave de fenda. Você pode trazer-ma?[**?**]
- Você vê os parafusos ao seu lado? Você pode-mos dar? [**?**]
- Preciso do martelo. Pode-me dá-lo? [**?**]
- Ah, a bomba de ar, deixei-a na segunda prateleira. Você pode-me trazê-la?[**?**]
- Eu não vejo o torquímetro. Você o procura por mim?[**?**] ou Procura-mo?[**?**].

Se houver pergunta semelhante no fórum, peço-lhes desconsiderem e apaguem esta. Obrigado!

Comment: @Artefacto, por que _se aplicariam_, e não _aplicar-se-iam_?

Comment: "Qual ou quais das construcoes ... se aplicariam...?": https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/colocacao-pronominal/  ("ocorre também a próclise nas orações iniciadas por palavras interrogativas")

Comment: A terceira e quarta soam-me mal.  Não é normal separar os pronomes, isso é possível normalmente quando vão com núcleos verbais diferentes, o que não é o caso aqui.  *Você pode trazer-mas* e *Pode dar-mos* (no padrão europeu não é normal subir os pronomes para o verbo poder, tipo *pode-mos dar*, mas acho que no padrão brasileiro se fosse que esse usasse os pronomes duplos, seria o mais normal nesse ordem (e escrito sem hífen: *pode mos dar*)

Answer (score 1):

> - Max, preciso da chave de fenda. Você pode trazer-ma?
> - Você vê os parafusos ao seu lado? Você pode-mos dar?

Estas duas não têm qualquer problema em termos de colocação dos clíticos. O grupo clítico (*ma* na primeira e *mos* na segunda) pode estar associado tanto ao verbo no infinitivo (*trazer*) como ao verbo *poder*. Nem todos os verbos permitem esta *subida do clítico* (a maioria dos que o permitem são auxiliares ou simi-auxiliares), mas com *poder* não há dúvida de que é possível. Por exemplo, Ana Martins, na *Gramática do Português* (cap. 65), dá esta lista (não exaustiva):

> Além dos verbos haver (de), estar (a), ter (a), ir, começar (a), dever, poder, querer, saber, [...] permitem igualmente a cliticização fora do domínio infinitivo os verbos andar (a), chegar (a), conseguir, continuar (a), ir a, fazer, ficar (a), mandar, pretender, tornar (a), vir (a), voltar.

Já estes casos são mais polémicos.

> - Preciso do martelo. Pode-me dá-lo?.
> - Ah, a bomba de ar, deixei-a na segunda prateleira. Você pode-me trazê-la?

Diz a mesma autora:

> [...] pode ainda não se formar o grupo clítico, cliticizando um dos clíticos ao verbo finito e o outro ao verbo infinitivo (*vou-lhe já devolvê-lo*). Esta última opção, embora não seja consensualmente
>   aceite como normativa, regista-se quer em corpora de língua falada quer de língua escrita.

Por fim:

> - Eu não vejo o torquímetro. Você o procura por mim? ou Procura-mo?

Para começar, a ênclise é obrigatória na primeira pergunta (pelo menos na norma europeia). A forma correta seria então:

> Procura-o por mim?

Depois, as duas perguntas não são equivalentes: *procura-mo* é mais parecido a *procura-o para mim*, ou seja, *me* é um dativo benefativo, indica a pessoa que beneficia da ação. *Por mim* indica que a outra pessoa estaria a substituir o falante na procura do objeto.

Mais informação: [capítulo 65 da *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/wochwel/documents/Cl%C3%ADticos_Gram%C3%A1tica%20do%20Portugu%C3%AAs_Gulbenkian.pdf).